# iOS StoreKit app (In-app purchase app) - When internet is not available

Tags: ios, ios4, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've got a question about In-App purchase app. All works fine without problems. But I'm thinking how to make "SKProduct list" (UITableView with issues) without internet connection. Is there any "best practice" way how to display stored issues? Thx for reply! ;)

Comment: you want to show some error message or alert to user?

Comment: No, I want same list which has been displayed last time when the device was online. But with disable buttons. I know how to do but I don't know if it is "best practice"... thx for ideas ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have following ways to save data for offline usage -
1. `NSUserDefaults`
2. In normal `text` file or `plist` file.
3. `SQLLite`

Each of these approach has some pros and cons, so it will depend on your need/requirement, which of above to use.

Apple provides `Reachability` Classes to check whether network connection is reachable or not, you can have this class in your app and determine when you are out of network, just do whatever you want(like disabling the button.)
Following is the developer link for Reachability Classes, where you can download the sample code and check how it actually works - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html